# Django-Nonrel: Multi-table inheritance is not supported by non-relational DBs

Tags: django, django-models, django-nonrel

I have a meta class named `MyModel`.

I also have 2 regular model classes named `Node` and `Author`. `Author` inherits from `MyModel`, and `Node` does not. (`Node` and `Author` work fine as expected.)

I want to change `Node` so that it also inherits from `MyModel`. When I try to change `Node` so that it also inherits from `MyModel` , I get the following error:

```
 raise DatabaseError("Multi-table inheritance is not "
TemplateSyntaxError: Caught DatabaseError while rendering: Multi-table inheritance is not supported by non-relational DBs.
```

I deleted all `Node` objects from the database, but I still get the error. Effectively, I want to delete `Node` and re-implement it. How can I get the database to recognize that `Node` should inherit from `MyModel`?

Comment: Did you reset app and done syncdb?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multi-table inheritance is not supported by django-nonrel.

If *MyModel* inherits from *django.db.models.Model* and *Node* and *Author* inherit from *MyModel*, then you have a multi table inheritance (even if *MyModel* has no fields).

You can avoid this by making *MyModel* an [abstract base class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes).